# Schedule the execution every day of a PDF report

Tags: report, pentaho, designer

I need to schedule the execution every day of a PDF report, I managed to schedule the execution of a job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, using Pentaho data integration and the Windows Task Scheduler.
If someone needs to do it, tell me.

Comment: *If someone needs to do it*. I don't. But I'm pretty sure the community will be glad to read how you do this, and it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'Start' object in 'Job' and double click to set schedule times.

your transform :

start -> get_transform -> end

if you want use windows scheduler use pentaho kettle or carte and start in windows scheduler .